# Remove options found in getopt from argv

Tags: php, command-line-interface, getopt

Is there a quick way to remove the found options with getopt from $argv?

Basically, I have

```
php trout.php --plugin dozer /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log
```

In my $options = getopt(); I have

```
Array
(
    [plugin] => dozer
)
```

And $argv has the following ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => --plugin
    [1] => dozer
    [2] => /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log
)
```

I would like $argv to have just

```
Array
(
    [0] => /opt/webapplications/Word/readme.log
)
```

I know there is array_shift to pop the first array element off, and I have seen loops in the past that just loop through the $argv popping all the elements off, however, I am wondering if there is a quick and easy way to do this with native php...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using

```
function __construct($args) {

    $this->options = getopt($this->shortopts, $this->longopts);

    array_shift($args);

    while(count($args) > 1) {

        if (strpos($args[0], '-') !== false && strpos($args[0], '-') == 0) {

            array_shift($args);

            if(in_array($args[0], $this->options)) {

                array_shift($args);
            }
        }
        else {

            break;
        }
    }

    $this->args = $args;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't take into account the option specified with a "=" like this: --plugin=dozer